# Saving array as CSV file using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, csv, string-comparison

This code analyzes the contents of two websites by taking all the `href` attributes from them. Then, It finds the ones that have the highest match of the href value from each array and save them to a CSV file. The problem is that when I open the file it brings back also the HTML data of my application.

As an exercise I can only use HTML and PHP

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
      website: 
      <input type="text" name="website1">
      <br>
      website: 
      <input type="text" name="website2">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

    // form has been submitted

    $url1 = $_POST['website1'];
    $url2 = $_POST['website2'];
    findAndCompare($url1, $url2);
    }
  else
    {
    }

function findAndCompare($url1, $url2)
    {
     libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    // Create a DOM parser object

    $dom1 = new DOMDocument();
    $dom2 = new DOMDocument();
    $dom1->loadHTMLFile($url1);
    $dom2->loadHTMLFile($url2);
    $arr1 = array();
    $arr2 = array();
    $arr3 = array();

    // Iterate over all the <a> tags

    foreach($dom1->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link)
        {

        // insert the <a href> in arr1

        array_push($arr1, $link->getAttribute('href'));
        }

    // Iterate over all the <a> tags

    foreach($dom2->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link)
        {

        // insert the <a href> in arr2

        array_push($arr2, $link->getAttribute('href'));
        }

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++)
        {
        $max_elem = $arr2[0];
        $max = 0;
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($arr2); $j++)
            {
            similar_text($arr1[$i], $arr2[$j], $perc);
            if ($perc > $max)
                {
                $max = $perc;
                $max_elem = $arr2[$j];
                }
            }

        $tmp = array($arr1[$i],$max_elem,$max);
        array_push($arr3,$tmp);
        }

    function convert_to_csv($input_array, $output_file_name, $delimiter)
        {
        $temp_memory = fopen('php://memory', 'w');

        // loop through the array

        foreach($input_array as $line)
            {

            // use the default csv handler

            fputcsv($temp_memory, $line, $delimiter);
            }

        fseek($temp_memory, 0);

        // modify the header to be CSV format

        header('Content-Type: application/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $output_file_name . '";');

        // output the file to be downloaded

        fpassthru($temp_memory);
        }

    convert_to_csv($arr3, 'export.csv', ',');
    }

?>
```

**UPDATE**
i solve it putting `ob_clean();` before `header`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML will indeed be output, because that is the first thing that your code does.

As you already know, PHP allows mixing of HTML and code within a single file, by use of the `<?php` and `?>` markers to denote the start and end of the PHP code.

Everything outside of those markers is considered output, and is sent to the browser in exactly the same way as if you'd used a `print()` or `echo()` statement.

Your code starts with a block of HTML, with nothing before it. This is exactly the same as if you'd started the program with a `print()` statement containing this HTML.

If you don't want the HTML to be output in all cases, then you need some code before it to tell it when and whether to output it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `header()` if there already is output.

Move the form html into the first else statement.

Also, make sure to enable error reporting, because php would have made this clear to you.